# VSTO: Count all Range.Find results

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I use the [`Find.HitHighlight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.hithighlight(v=office.15).aspx) method to mark all occurrences of a particular word.
In addition, I want to show the user the words, or scroll to them, or even just count how many words were found.

I am currently using this code:

```
Word.Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
range.Find.HitHighlight(
     FindText: "dog",
     MatchCase: false, MatchWholeWord: true,
     HighlightColor: item.color);
```

The question is, is there a way to get back one of the requests I mentioned, using the [`Find.HitHighlight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.hithighlight(v=office.15).aspx) method, or using another method, or there is no choice but to use the following code:

```
var text = range.Text.Split(' ');
text.Count(word => word.Equals("dog"));
```

(I prefer not to use this code, because I believe there is a way to use MSWord's tools and not take all the text myself)

Comment: Mmm, actually Word has this tool already built in, in the more recent versions. Press Ctrl+F to get the Find pane. Type in the term you want to search at the top and Word will show you the entire list - choose the one that interests from the list...

Comment: Yes, Of course I know that! I just needed to do this in a programming way.

Comment: OK - not everyone coming from the C# side always knows these things :-) Just wanted to be sure you really do want to "re-invent the wheel"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the Word object model that will return all the "hits" found using `HitHighlight`. It's simply not designed to return non-contiguous Range collections, generally, according to any particular attributes.

If you just want a count, the C# code you already have is probably fastest in execution. You'd lose any formatting and location information, but for a count that's not important.

For anything else you'd need to do a regular `Find.Execute`, in a loop, adding each found `Range` to an array (or whatever). That would allow you to show a list to the user with surrounding text, for example.

When you use `Range.Find` (as opposed to `Document.Content.Find`) on a successful Find the `Range` object contains the found text. The trick with something like this is, after a successful Find it's necessary to reset the Range in order to continue. Something like this (typed from memory, so maybe syntax errors):

```
Word.Range rngDoc = wrdDocument.Content;
Word.Range rngFind = rngDoc.Duplicate;
bool bFound = true;
object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
while (bFound)
{
  bFound = rngFind.Find.Execute(/*params here*/);
  if (bFound)
  {
     //Do something with rngFind
     //Set the start of the Range to search AFTER what was found
     rngFind.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
     //and extend it to the end of the original Range
     // in this case the entire document
     rngFind.End = rngDoc.End;
  }
}
```